# Does Get-ADUser have some form of caching?

Tags: powershell

I have been using Get-ADUser with my work but it seems to be caching the results to where it says its locked after the account is unlocked and the person is logged in.

Is there some undocumented feature somewhere in this command that caches the results or is this likely a setting of the Domain Controller?

Comment: If you store your `Get-ADUser` results into a variable, that variable will not update when something about that user changes in AD. Since AD typically has multiple domain controllers that replicate to each other, it is possible that not every domain controller has the same data at a given time. If you are not using the `-Server` parameter, there is a chance you are not using the same DC or global catalog service per query. Also, if you make a change, you make that on a writable DC. You could be reading from a read-only DC that has not seen the change yet.

Comment: the most  common cause of  what you seem to be seeing is caused DC sync timing. just as `AdminOfThings` mentioned, the standard fix is to always use the `-Server` parameter with the same DC name. [*grin*]

Comment: Your both likely right. I was running the command for it directly and it was staying Locked status true even though the direct access to the account showed false. They must copy their results from our DC from another DC or system after some kind of delay. I wish there was some other way then to get this status.